# make javascript image randomizer responsive with css?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, responsive

I'm a front-end web designer with really little understanding of javascript, but I wanted to include a javascript-based image randomizer (to where the image would change each time the user refreshed the page) but the only problem is I'm really unsure how to make the element responsive through CSS. I'm not even sure if it's possible, at this point, but I've tried enclosing the script within divs and also giving the img tag a class and adding that to the CSS and nothing seems to work.

The script itself that I found works great, but I need to be able to apply styles (especially responsive styles!) to it and I'm just really stumped.

Here's the script itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var total_images = 3;
        var random_number = Math.floor((Math.random()*total_images));
        var random_img = new Array();
        random_img[0] = '<a href="page1.html"><img class="center" src="red.png"></a>';
        random_img[1] = '<a href="page2.html"><img class="center" src="blue.png"></a>';
        random_img[2] = '<a href="page3.html"><img class="center" src="placeholderbanner.png"></a>';
        document.write(random_img[random_number]);
        </script>
```

Does anyone have some good advice about how to go about doing this? I'd really appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

just add the below to your CSS or put it in  tags

```
    .center {
        float: left;
        max-width: 100%;
     }
```

Comment: I've tried this approach, but it doesn't affect the images within the script at all. I'd also like for it to just affect the images within the script, rather than all things using the img tag on my website. I've tried putting it within a larger div (like, closing the script within a div named something like "cover" and styling that on my css page, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: try the above code...but this worked for me ...so if you can provide some more info ...that would be great